# About Swift Api calling

Tags: swift

I have few theoretical doubts about api calls. I just wanted to know suppose if there are 4 api calls in one controller which are dependent on one another then how should I call them.
for ex

```
call A() 
call B() 
call C() 
call D()//give A,B,C output to D AS input
```

Another doubt is if there are 2 calls in one controller which have no connection with each other then is it a good practice to use serial queue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`DispatchGroup`** for this kind of scenario.

**1.** Create an instance of `DispatchGroup`

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

**2.** Create `aOutput, bOutput, cOutput` to store the api responses received after calling methods of `A(), B(), C()`.

```
var aOutput = ""
var bOutput = ""
var cOutput = ""
```

**3.** Call `enter()` and `leave()` methods on `dispatchGroup` inside `A(), B(), C()`

```
func A() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    if let url = URL(string: "") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            aOutput = "A Done"
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
}

func B() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    if let url = URL(string: "") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            bOutput = "B Done"
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
}

func C() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    if let url = URL(string: "") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            cOutput = "C Done"
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
}

func D() {
    //use aOutput, bOutput, cOutput here
    print(aOutput, bOutput, cOutput)
}
```

**4.** Add an observer to `dispatchGroup` to notify when all 3 api responses are received.

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    //A, B, C - Done
    D()
}
```

**5.** Now, call the methods `A(), B(), C()` from your controller,

```
func callApis() {
    A()
    B()
    C()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Regularly, Swift is synchronous, which means that B() will be called **after** A() finishes it's execution. The same for B and C and so on.

If you want to pass the output it would look like this:

```swift
let resultA = A()
let resultB = B()
let resultB = C()
D(resultA, resultB, resultC)
```

What do these 2 calls in the controller do? They have something in common like accessing the same resource?

Serial Queue are good for executing one task at a time, useful when you don't want two tasks to access the same File for example.

A concurrent one would allow both tasks to access the same file at the same time (which could cause issues)

Comment: thanks for the answer. the other 2 call doesn't have anything common.  and another thing is if you have more than 4 calls which doesn't have anything do to with each other how should i do call that concurrently?. so that my ui does not freeze for some time

Comment: You can use something like this: let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrent.queue", attributes: .concurrent); concurrentQueue.async{ callA() }; concurrentQueue.async{ callB() }; concurrentQueue.async{ callC() }; concurrentQueue.async{ callD() } (please forgive the lack of formatting, I am on my phone, will edit later)